# check API requirements crx/extension/chrome/chromium

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, crx

I have an unpacked crx extension file, and want to know/check which chrome API's it uses, i cant find anything about this through my search engines, and have normally nothing to do with browser stuff.

Edit: i want to do this just by hand, code implementation comes way later and should than be self explanatory ...

Edit: Here we go, wrapped inside "permissions" "class", i searched for "API" reference instead: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/declare_permissions/

Comment: See `permissions` in manifest.json.

Comment: ouh, thanks @wOxxOm, i was so blind, even had a look at it some mins ago, i don't get the format completly, each api perm is inside "*", but outside the simple strings there are also URL's, maybe u got a quick reference to a documentation about the whole permissions class? Or can extensions dynamically somehow import whole api's? Edit: it's not extra declared as "host_permissions", like the optional ones! Edit2: are those URLS just straight the websites the extension can access? Pretty hard mix inside one perm "class" ...